# Strongly-Typed Route Testing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, moq

If I understand [the example](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) correctly, MvcContrib TestHelper has a strongly-typed test of a route mapping to a particular controller.  The down-side is that again, if I understand the example, the route being tested does not come from the global.asax file; It instead comes from the test setup.

In contrast, the book "Pro ASP.NET MVC3 Framework" shares route-test helpers that actually do leverage the routes in the global.asax file.  These helpers, however, are not strong typed (or even loose-typed) to a particular controller:

```
    [TestMethod]  //sample from the book...
    public void TestIncomingRoutes() {     
        // check for the URL that we hope to receive     
        TestRouteMatch("~/Admin/Index", "Admin", "Index"); 
    }
```

I'd like to have the best of both worlds.  Has anyone a link to helper code that (1) expressly identifies a particular controller, (2) uses the routes in the global.asax for the tests and (3) is not married to Rhino Mocks - as I prefer MOQ.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to test your HttpApplication subclass (global.asax.cs code) to ensure it calls the code to register the routes.  I'm not sure that's really necessary, as it will be pretty apparent that nothing works if you fail to do so.  OTOH, the MvcContrib is allowing you to test that the URLs you want actually map to something, which has a lot of value if you've carefully designed your urls to be SEO friendly.  That is worth testing, IMO.